# Trial Multiplication for Factorization

Tags: algorithm, r

I am trying a trial multiplication for factorization. This is a general example, but each sequence can be specified to pairs of sequences \${p,q}\$ for a given \$n\$. For example, if \$n\$ ended in 3, then {\$p,q\$} would be: {1,3},{3,1},{7,9} and {9,7} with sequence steps of -10 and 10 respectively.

The essence of the method is if \$pq < n\$, raise \$q\$. If \$pq > n\$, lower \$p\$ while continuing where the last \$p\$ and the last \$q\$ left off.

```
#Trial Multiplication
TM<- function (number){

    if (floor(sqrt(number))%%2==0)
    p_start <<- floor(sqrt(number))-1

    if (floor(sqrt(number))%%2>0)  
    p_start <<- floor(sqrt(number))

    if (ceiling(sqrt(number))%%2==0)
    q_start <<- ceiling(sqrt(number))+1

    if (ceiling(sqrt(number))%%2>0)  
    q_start <<- ceiling(sqrt(number)) 



    for (p in seq(p_start,1,-1)){   
      for (q in seq(q_start,number,1)){    

      #Quick primality tests for p and q... 
      #if(p%%3==0 | p%%5==0 | p%%7==0 | p%%11==0 | p%%13==0 | p%%17==0 | p%%19==0) break
      #if(q%%3==0 | q%%5==0 | q%%7==0 | q%%11==0 | q%%13==0 | q%%17==0 | q%%19==0) next 


      if(p*q==number)
      return(c(p,q)) 

      if(p*q>number) break


      q_start<<- q
      p_start<<- p

      }


  #if(q%%3==0 | q%%5==0 | q%%7==0 | q%%11==0 | q%%13==0 | q%%17==0 | q%%19==0) break
  #if(p%%3==0 | p%%5==0 | p%%7==0 | p%%11==0 | p%%13==0 | p%%17==0 | p%%19==0) next 


  if(p*q==number)
  return(c(p,q))  

  if(p*q<number) break

  p_start<<- p
  q_start<<- q

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give more details or examples about how the algorithm is supposed to work? Or maybe a link to the methodology. The example you gave is hard to understand. Also, I'm not sure I understand the use of `(q%%3==0 | q%%5==0 | q%%7==0 | q%%11==0 | q%%13==0 | q%%17==0 | q%%19==0)`. Most numbers are indeed divisible by the few first prime numbers so the double loop will essentially skip all the time. Testing your function with sample numbers, it either dies or returns nothing (i.e. keeps skiping the double loop)...

Comment: I have not run into an instance of the function dying or returning nothing.  Ideally, it would only multiply the primes within the sequences.  However, using just the identified sequences of 1's, 3's, 7's and 9's is more efficient than 6k+- 1.  Unfortunately it is slow (hence the posting here for possible efficiency enhancements), and you can add a print command within the q loop to demonstrate the operations.  I have notes on this and another method available here:  (https://www.scribd.com/doc/245859553/Naive-Grouping-Trial-Multiplication-for-Factorization-Notes)

Comment: Start a new session. Paste the code you wrote above. Then try `TM(7)` (fails) and `TM(10)` or `TM(1234)` (they return nothing).

Comment: I see your point for small numbers.  Eliminating the quick primality tests and decreasing the steps to -1 and 1 for p and q respectively will work for those instances.  Try TM(1927) which should return the factors and then try TM(1051) which returns nothing and is prime.  Adding print(c(p,q)) after the break in the q loop will show the operations.

Comment: Ok, so `TM(1927)` works... But if you try `for (i in 1900:2000) print(TM(i))`, you will see that only four numbers in that range return something... What does it say about the algorithm? Is the methodology wrong or just the implementation? `2000` looks like a simple number to work with (`= 2^4 * 5^3`): what should the algorithm return and can you walk us through the steps?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, quite useful.  Only four numbers are returned because they have factors not divisible by the quick primality tests.  Half of the numbers are even, so those are immediately skipped.  13 are prime (http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt).  Put a # in front of the quick primality tests in both the p and q loops and you will find the rest.  2000 is even, thus the steps have to be reduced to -1 and 1 and the "to" in the p sequence needs to be reduced to 2.

Comment: It is still hard to understand the end goal. Should the function return something for all numbers? I'm tempted to think so: even a prime `n` could return `c(1, n)`.If yes, can you edit and fix your code? If no, can you explain what the function is supposed to do. (The idea here being: focus on writing code that works first. Make sure you test it thoroughly, using the `for` loop I showed you for example. Only after, you can work on making it faster.)

Comment: If you make those above mentioned changes, then it returns something for all numbers (reduce "to" to 1 for primes).  The end goal was to have something faster than trial division given the same number of possible factors.  Even numbers and numbers ending in 5 aren't interesting or difficult to factor.  The product of two primes has to end in 1, 3, 7 and 9 and given a specific number there are only 4 combinations of p and q that can generate it.  Using all of this information and the fact that multiplying is faster than division for large n should yield a very fast algorithm...should!...

Comment: Please make the changes yourself. Use the *edit* button.

Comment: Edited, please let me know if it works for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is slow is to create `seq(q_start,number,1)`. Take the example where  `number` is 298,716,239: you are asking R to create a vector of nearly 300 million integers. It chokes. Instead of looping over sequences created in memory, it is easier to just keep the current value, increment and limit in memory. See for example:

```
TM <- function (n) {

   n <- as.integer(n)
   r <- sqrt(n)
   p <- as.integer(floor(r))
   q <- as.integer(ceiling(r))

   while (p >= 1L & q <= n) {
      if (p * q == n) return(c(p, q)) 
      if (p * q > n) { p <- p - 1L } else { q <- q + 1L } 
   }
   stop("hmm... we should not be here...")
}

TM(1900)
TM(298716239)
```

Now that's a start... If you try with a large prime, e.g. `298716247`, it will take a very long time to converge towards `1 * 298716247` though. So you will have to get more creative to make it converge faster. At least, you should be fixed about why your original code was so slow.

---

Edit: here is an idea I got for making it converge faster where you update both `p` and `q` at each iteration. I hope the math checks out and I did not leave a corner case:

```
TM2 <- function (n){

   n <- as.integer(n) # everything is faster with integers
   r <- sqrt(n)
   p <- as.integer(floor(r))
   q <- as.integer(ceiling(r))
   while (p >= 1L & q <= n) {
      if (p * q == n) return(c(p, q)) 
      if (p*q > n) {
         p <- p - 1L
         q <- as.integer(floor(n / p))
      } else {
         q <- q + 1L
         p <- as.integer(ceiling(n / q))
      } 
   }
   stop("hmm...")
}

TM2(1900)
TM2(298716239)
TM2(298716247)
```

Comment: This is a lot faster and I am clear on why my original code was so slow, thank you @flodel.  The creative aspect for faster convergence I had in mind is to run paired lists {1,9} etc. with a -10L and +10L in parallel with the 3 remaining paired lists {3,3},{7,7} and {9,1} (for this example of 298,716,239).